# Xamarin UI/Unit Tests with Realm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I've created an app with **Xamarin.Forms** that is using **realm** to store information.

I wanted to write some tests to check that logout function in my application is working correctly and the realm is empty of data.

In a separate solution I installed the **Realm 0.82.1** packages and created references to the PCL solution to reference the models to begin testing.

When changing the models an exception is thrown as migration is needed:

```cs
public static class RealmHelper {
    public static Realm GetInstance() {
        var config = new RealmConfiguration(Constants.REALM_FILE);
        try {
            return Realm.GetInstance(config);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Realm.DeleteRealm(config); // Error Thrown here
            return Realm.GetInstance(config);
        }
    }
}
```

However this error is thrown

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException : The PCL build of Realm is being
>   linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a
>   platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.

**My Test**

```cs
[Test]
public void CanInitDB() {
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() =>
    {
        new DataAccessController();
    });
}
```

**My Controller**

```cs
public class DataAccessController {
    static Realm realm;

    public DataAccessController() {
        realm = RealmHelper.GetInstance();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1059

Answer (score 0):

Realm doesn't support using the PCL version without a platform-specific counterpart. What you could do is use [Xamarin's built-in test runners](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/) that will produce an application that you can use to execute tests on a device/simulator. It's slightly inconvenient, but should get the job done.

Comment: I have actually followed this guide to set up my tests. However I'm still getting errors:

`Expected: No Exception to be thrown
  But was:   (The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.)`

How do I link the platform-specific dll in the test suite?

Comment: You need to reference the Realm nuget from the test runner project.